# Problema de conversão de fonte Delphi7 para DelphiXE7

Tags: delphi

Eu tenho um certo código fonte para controlar microterminais da marca Gertec que foi compilado em Delphi7 e funciona tudo ok, quando eu compilo em delphi XE7 ocorrem alguns problemas.

Para quem não sabe micro terminal é [isso](http://www.extra-imagens.com.br/Informatica/automacaocomercial/RegistradoraseMicroterminais/5139174/269098975/MicroTerminal-Nao-Fiscal-Gertec-MT-720-conexao-TCP-IP-5139174.jpg).

Utilizo a seguinte função para mandar texto para o display:

```
procedure TFTerminalSys.EnviaMensagem(Mensagem:String;Linha:Integer);
var
    buf: array [0..255] of BYTE;
    limitechar:Integer;
begin
    LimparLinha(Linha);
    PosicionarCursor(Linha,1);
    Try
    // Verifica se há algum terminal selecionado
    if (ListBox1.ItemIndex = -1) then
    begin
        Application.MessageBox('Selecione um terminal.','Display',48)
    end
    else
    begin
        System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy(@buf,Copy(Mensagem,1,20));

        // Envia o comando de DisplayString para o terminal
        if mt_dispstr(id_selecionado, buf[0]) < 1 then
        begin
            Application.MessageBox('Erro enviando comando.','ERRO',16);
        end;
    end;
    Except
        Application.MessageBox('Preencha corretamento os campos.','Display',48);
    end;
end;
```

Esta função foi alterada, o fonte veio em Delphi7, a única diferença foi que tive que mudar a linha

```
"StrPCopy(@buf,Copy(Mensagem,1,20));"
```

para

```
"System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy(@buf,Copy(Mensagem,1,20));"
```

Esta mudança por algum motivo *buga* meu retorno de dados, e se eu não alterar para `"System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy"` a minha mensagem não vai pro terminal corretamente, apenas o primeiro caractere é enviado(porem se rodar o exemplo que veio em Delphi7 sem alterações tudo funciona corretamente).

Enfim não entendo por que a função de enviar dados para o terminal esta bugando o retorno de dados. Segue a baixo a função que eu uso para retornar os dados vindos do terminal:

```
procedure TFTerminalSys.HabilitaResposta(Senha:Boolean = False);
var
    buf : array [0..255] of BYTE;
    estado: DWORD;
begin

    // Verifica se há algum terminal selecionado
    if (ListBox1.ItemIndex = -1) then
    begin
        Application.MessageBox('Selecione um terminal.','Display',48)
    end
    else
    begin
        if (Senha) then
        begin
            estado := 1
        end
        else
        begin
            estado := 0;
        end;

        // Envia o comando de EditString para o terminal
        if mt_seteditstring(Id_selecionado,buf[0],1,estado) < 1 then
        begin
            Application.MessageBox('Erro enviando comando.','ERRO',16);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Que diga-se de passagem, tambem não funciona corretamente depois que compilei em Delphi XE7, em vez de retornar os dados corretamente, retorna o que parece serem lixos de memoria. Por exemplo: quando digito '222' no micro terminal é retornado '4þUaE222' (dentre outros caracteres estranhos), se fosse sempre um numero fixo de lixo eu poderia usar um copy e começar a pegar o retorno a partir de quando acaba os caracteres lixo, mas o numero de lixo não é fixo. O que é estranho é que o lixo no retorno muda se eu mudar a função de enviar texto ao terminal (primeira função que eu colei lá em cima). Segue abaixo o exemplo :

1º caso: Mudando a linha `"StrPCopy(@buf,Copy(Mensagem,1,20));"` para `"System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy(@buf,Copy(Mensagem,1,20))"` e enviando '222' ao terminal

Resultado: 4þ@aEÓAi2

2º caso: deixando a linha `"StrPCopy(@buf,Copy(Mensagem,1,20));"` inalterada e enviando '222' ao terminal

Resultado: 4þUaEÓ´%222

No segundo caso eu recebo uma resposta mais estável, eu poderia usar um Copy e recortar somente a parte sem lixo, mas lembrando que eu altero a linha `"StrPCopy(@buf,Copy(Mensagem,1,20));"` para `"System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy(@buf,Copy(Mensagem,1,20));"` pois caso contrário, a mensagem não envia ao display do terminal corretamente, só é enviado o primeiro caracter, por exemplo "Bem vindo" enviaria só "B"

Minha duvida é por que este lixo de memoria aparece, e por que se eu rodar a versão do Delphi7 funciona corretamente?

Comment: A versão StrPCopy do SysUtils foi descontinuada. Veja: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.StrPCopy
O correto mesmo é você utilizar a System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy.

Faça um teste e utilize a seguinte função, veja se te ajuda:
`function StrPCopyCustomizada(const Source: AnsiString; Dest: PAnsiChar): PAnsiChar;
begin
  Move(PAnsiChar(Source)^, Dest^, Length(Source) + 1); // +1 for the 0 char
  Result := Dest;
end;`

Se der certo por favor avise que eu edito esse comentário e posto a resposta certinha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na função:

```
System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy(@buf,Copy(Mensagem,1,20));
```

Este método espera que Source (o segundo parâmetro) seja do tipo `AnsiString`. Mas perceba que você declarou o parâmetro `Mensagem` como uma `String`:

```
procedure TFTerminalSys.EnviaMensagem(Mensagem:String;Linha:Integer);
```

Em versões mais novas do Delphi o tipo `string` passou a ser um alias de `UnicodeString`. Por consequência `Mensagem` acaba sendo um `UnicodeString`, causando o comportamento indefinido.

Para consertar, converta a string explicitamente para uma AnsiString:

```
System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy(@buf, AnsiString(Copy(Mensagem,1,20)));
```